# Why am I not able to change worksheet reference?

Tags: excel, vba

First, I apologize in advance if this question is too obvious.  I just haven't worked with VBA and Excel in a few years and I can't find the answer to my question elsewhere.

I want my VBA program to take data from the worksheet "ReportData" and use it to create some pivot tables on a new worksheet "Report".

The question I have is about cell reference.  I thought that, as long as you activate or select a worksheet, then that worksheet becomes the point of reference for VBA.  Thus, a statement like Cells(1,1).Value will look at the value in the first cell of the active sheet.  But, I don't know why it isn't working for me.

This is the version that works for me:

```
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim ReportSheet As Worksheet
Dim ItemName As String
Dim Row As Long, Col As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Delete Report sheet if it exists
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Report").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

'Add Report sheet
Set ReportSheet = Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Report"

'Create Pivot Cache
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=Sheets("ReportData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

Row = 1
For i = 1 To 4
    For Col = 1 To 7
        ItemName = Sheets("ReportData").Cells(1, i + 2)

        With Sheets("Report").Cells(Row, Col)
            .Value = ItemName
            .Font.Size = 16
        End With
    .
    .
    .
    .
    Next Col    
Next i
```

My question is about the following line:

> With Sheets("Report").Cells(Row, Col)

Why do I need to add

> "Sheets("Report")."

?  I thought the last activated sheet was "Report".  Thus, if I use:

> With Cells(Row, Col)

alone - shouldn't that automatically refer to

> Sheets("Report").Cells(Row, Col)

? (It doesn't).

I also, tried activating the "Report" worksheet just before I make reference to the cells and that did not work either.  For example, the following did not work for me.  It keeps on referring to the cells in the "ReportData" worksheet (that is not the worksheet I want to reference):

```
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim ReportSheet As Worksheet
Dim ItemName As String
Dim Row As Long, Col As Long, i As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Delete Report sheet if it exists
On Error Resume Next
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Sheets("Report").Delete
On Error GoTo 0

'Add Report sheet
Set ReportSheet = Worksheets.Add
ActiveSheet.Name = "Report"

'Create Pivot Cache
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
SourceData:=Sheets("ReportData").Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

Row = 1
For i = 1 To 4
    For Col = 1 To 7
        ItemName = Sheets("ReportData").Cells(1, i + 2)

        Worksheets("Report").Activate

        With Cells(Row, Col)
            .Value = ItemName
            .Font.Size = 16
        End With
    .
    .
    .
    .
    Next Col    
Next i
```

What does this second example not work?  It is driving me insane.  I thought all you had to do was first activate - or select - a worksheet and then any cell reference you make after that would be for the cells in the worksheet that you had activated or selected.  Am I going crazy here?

Comment: Code works here as expected - even without explicit reference. 1. Insert `Application.EnableEvents = False` before the loops to check if a macro interferes. 2. Set a breakpoint at the line `ItemName=...` and single step (F8), checking `?activesheet.name` in the direct window after each step.

Comment: Instead of `Worksheets("Report").Activate` try a `ReportSheet.Activate`. If you still need a sheet reference use the `ReportSheet` object instead of `Sheets("Report")`.

Comment: user1016274 thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This type of question is fairly common on this site ... and is usually followed by a list of comments from willing respondents asking if you are capturing this or that event, working on different workbooks, changing sheet names, activating other sheets, etc. The point is, no one can say for sure what's wrong - us or you - because you don't have control of your objects.

VBA is just like a toddler; with uncontrolled objects you're saying:

> Hey, go in the sweet shop and I'll be back in 5 minutes ... oh, and
>   those kids from the naughty *OtherMacros* family might be there too.

Beautiful though your baby undoubtedly is, it's going to be spending an awful lot of time on the naughty step!

I've adjusted your code to give you more control so that it isn't reliant on active workbooks and sheets, Selections, default properties, etc. It should get you started in the right direction ... and nowhere near that sweetshop called `Activate`.

Oh, and you don't need to loop through every cell in a `Range` to copy its values to a new `Range`, you can just read it into a `Variant` and write that whole `Variant` to the new `Range`.

```
Public Sub RunMe()
    Const DATA_SHEET_NAME As String = "ReportData"
    Const REPORT_SHEET_NAME As String = "Report"
    Dim dataSheet As Worksheet
    Dim reportSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ptCache As PivotCache
    Dim v As Variant
    Dim b As Boolean

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set dataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(DATA_SHEET_NAME)

    'Delete Report sheet if it exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(REPORT_SHEET_NAME)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not reportSheet Is Nothing Then
        b = Application.DisplayAlerts
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        reportSheet.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = b
    End If

    'Add Report sheet
    Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    reportSheet.Name = REPORT_SHEET_NAME

    'Create Pivot Cache
    Set ptCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
                  SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                  SourceData:=reportSheet.Range("A1").CurrentRegion)

    'Write the item names
    v = dataSheet.Range("C1").Resize(, 7).Value2
    With reportSheet.Range("A1").Resize(, UBound(v, 2))
        .Value = v
        .Font.Size = 16
    End With

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Ambie, thanks a lot for your help.  From you code, these lines helped me the most:

Set reportSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
reportSheet.Name = REPORT_SHEET_NAME


Once I started using reportSheet as a reference, things worked great.  Thanks!