# The Ubiquitous: Application defined or object defined error

Tags: excel, if-statement, error-handling, sendkeys, vba

I wrote a little macro that enters transactions into our ERP system and things seem to get gummed up when it's determining whether or not the second location defined in the spreadsheet is greater than zero.  Here is my code:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub DblChk()

If (MsgBox("Are you sure you are ready to append scrap data to QAD? This cannot be reversed.", vbOKCancel)) = 1 Then

Call Scrap

Else: Exit Sub

End If

End Sub

Sub Scrap()

On Error GoTo ErrorHelper

Sheets("Roundup").Select

Range("I2").Select

Call Shell("C:\Program Files\QAD\QAD Enterprise Applications 2.9.6\QAD.Applications.exe", vbNormalFocus)

'Sign in to QAD
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
SendKeys ("username")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
SendKeys ("password")
SendKeys ("{ENTER}")

'Enter Scrap

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

'Scrap Loop

Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)

If ActiveCell.Value > 0 Then

ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Activate
SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Activate
SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Activate
SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys ("SCRAP")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Activate
SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Activate
SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
SendKeys ("{TAB}")
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Activate

Else

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate

End If

Loop
ErrorHelper:
MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

I've seen several references to this error on the internet but none that seem to apply to my specific situation.  It seems to be going awry at the beginning of the If statement.

Any thoughts?

Comment: A couple of thoughts: 1. you don't have control of the worksheet when you use `ActiveCell`. The active cell can belong to any worksheet that happens to be the active one, so there's no guarantee your macro is working on the sheet you think it is. Try: `Set ws = Workbooks([your book name]).Worksheets([your sheet name]` then refer to the cell by using the `Cell` property of that worksheet, `ws.Cells([row, col])` 2. You haven't covered the case that in `ActiveCell.Value > 0` is not numeric.

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  1. Does having the "Sheets" and "Range" lines at the beginning of the Scrap Macro give me control of the worksheet and starting line?  2. Should I be concerned about non-numeric values if the column in question is auto-populated?  The sheet this macro runs on is invisible to the public.  If so, do I cover this with an "OR" statement?

Comment: This is a great case in point. If your worksheet is hidden and you have the line `Sheets("Roundup").Activate`, then add `MsgBox Activesheet.Name` as the next line and see what it says. BTW `Sheets("Roundup").Select` will throw an error as you can't `Select` a worksheet.

Comment: @Ambie I see what you mean.  I was so sure that #2 was impossible that I didn't bother to look.  The last cell focus command before 'Else' has it moving in the wrong direction to a non-auto-populated range that happens to be, you guessed it, non-numeric.  Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem. In VBA, using unreferenced properties always leads to trouble - my rule is always avoid them. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321586/why-am-i-not-able-to-change-worksheet-reference/33324815#33324815

Comment: I was trying to rewrite your code and explain the issues but actually It's very difficult to figure what you are trying to achieve as the code keeps referring to the active cell and it keeps changing the activate cell in every line that is not sendkeys, could you write beside the lines to which cell the instruction refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done some adjustments to your code *(see comments within code)*

```
Sub DblChk()
    Rem This line is enough anything else is redundant
    If MsgBox("Are you sure you are ready to append scrap data to QAD? This cannot be reversed.", vbOKCancel) = 1 Then Call Scrap
End Sub
```

This is your code revised, note use of declared variables, it still shows original lines "commented"

General assumption is that the Offset commands always refer to the `ActiveCell` in this line:

`Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)`
replace by this
`Do While rCll.Value2 <> Empty`

Note the addition of the `Exit Sub` line before the `ErrorHelper` line otherwise it will always show the error message even if there is no error.

```
Sub Scrap()
Dim rCll As Range
On Error GoTo ErrorHelper

''    Sheets("Roundup").Select
''    Range("I2").Select
    Set rCll = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Roundup").Range("I2") 'If Procedure resides is Workbook with data
    'Set rCll = Workbooks(WbkName).Sheets("Roundup").Range("I2") 'If Procedure does not reside is Workbook with data

    Call Shell("C:\Program Files\QAD\QAD Enterprise Applications 2.9.6\QAD.Applications.exe", vbNormalFocus)

    'Sign in to QAD
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        SendKeys ("username")
        SendKeys ("{TAB}")
        SendKeys ("password")
        SendKeys ("{ENTER}")

    'Enter Scrap
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
        SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    'Scrap Loop
'    Do While Not IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    Do While rCll.Value2 <> Empty
    Rem ActiveCell.Value2=empty is more accurate than IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
        With rCll

            If .Value2 > 0 Then

'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -8).Activate
'                    SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, -8).Value2)

'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6).Activate
                SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
'                SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, 6).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Activate
'                SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, -1).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                SendKeys ("SCRAP")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Activate
'                SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, 2).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, -4).Activate
'                SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, -4).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

'                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
'                SendKeys (ActiveCell.Value)
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, 1).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
                SendKeys ("{ENTER}")

'                ActiveCell.Offset(1, -4).Activate
                Set rCll = .Offset(1, -4)

            Else
'                ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
                rCll = .Offset(1, 0)

        End If: End With

    Loop

Exit Sub
ErrorHelper:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```

However you can avoid the use of the Do...Loop by identifying and declaring your target range earlier

```
Sub Scrap_Using_Range()
Dim rTrg As Range
Dim rCll As Range
On Error GoTo ErrorHelper


    Set rCll = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Roundup").Range("I2") 'If Procedure resides is Workbook with data
    'Set rCll = Workbooks(WbkName).Sheets("Roundup").Range("I2") 'If Procedure does not reside is Workbook with data

    With rCll
        Set rTrg = IIf(.Offset(1, 0).Value2 = Empty, .Cells, Range(.Cells, .Cells.End(xlDown)))
    End With

    Call Shell("C:\Program Files\QAD\QAD Enterprise Applications 2.9.6\QAD.Applications.exe", vbNormalFocus)

    'Sign in to QAD
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))
        SendKeys ("username")
        SendKeys ("{TAB}")
        SendKeys ("password")
        SendKeys ("{ENTER}")

    'Enter Scrap
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:15"))
        SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        SendKeys ("{TAB}")
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))

    'Scrap Loop
    For Each rCll In rTrg
        With rCll
            If .Value2 > 0 Then
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, -8).Value2)

                SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, 6).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, -1).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                SendKeys ("SCRAP")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

                Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
                SendKeys (.Offset(0, 2).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

                SendKeys (.Offset(0, -4).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{TAB}")

                SendKeys (.Offset(0, 1).Value2)
                SendKeys ("{ENTER}")
                SendKeys ("{ENTER}")

    End If: End With: Next

Exit Sub
ErrorHelper:
    MsgBox Err.Description

End Sub
```