# how to simulate an excel formula in VBA to run automatically

Tags: vba, excel, formatting

So I get the date in the following format: 201603

and it needs to be rearranged into 03/2016.

If this is in cell A1: 201603

and this is in cell B1: `=RIGHT(A1,2) & "/" & LEFT(A1,4)`

the rearrangement will occur just fine when used as a formula. The issue I am having is putting this into VBA so that it will run automatically for dumps of data that are incorrectly formatted.

My code seems to get a mismatch error and I dont really see the problem.

All feedback is appreciated.

```
Sub format ()
    initial_date = Range ("A1").Value
    Dim Publish_date As Date
    publish_date = DateValue(Mid(initial_date,1,4) & "/" & Mid(initial_date,5,2))
    Range("A1").Value = publish_date
End Sub
```

[Screenshot of what i am working with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4NCa.jpg)

Comment: The code works fine for me. It doesn't do what you say you want to do, but it doesn't give any error.

Comment: There are a number of reasons you'd get that error but I'd bet my house it's because `initial_date` is `Empty` ... and I'd bet my dog in that house it's because your active sheet isn't the one your data is on (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321586/why-am-i-not-able-to-change-worksheet-reference/33324815#33324815).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use DATESERIAL() in vba and then apply a number format to the cell:

```
Sub format()
Dim initial_date As String
Dim Publish_date As Date

initial_date = Range("A1").value
Publish_date = DateSerial(Mid(initial_date, 1, 4), Mid(initial_date, 5, 2), 1)

Range("A1").value = Publish_date
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"

End Sub
```

---

And to iterate through the entire column:

```
Sub format()
Dim initial_date As String
Dim Publish_date As Date
Dim lastrow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If IsDate(.Cells(i, 1)) Then
            .Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"
        Else
            initial_date = .Cells(i, 1).value
            Publish_date = DateSerial(Mid(initial_date, 1, 4), Mid(initial_date, 5, 2), 1)

            .Cells(i, 1).value = Publish_date
            .Cells(i, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"
        End If
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

---

If you are convinced that the whole column is in the same format `yyyymm` then you can do the whole at once:

```
Sub format()
Dim lastrow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row
    .Range("A1:A" & lastrow) = .Evaluate("Index(DATE(Mid(A1:A" & lastrow & ",1,4),Mid(A1:A" & lastrow & ",5,2),1),)")
    .Range("A1:A" & lastrow).NumberFormat = "mm/yyyy"
End With

End Sub
```